# Wordpress URL issues after update to 5.5.1

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, yoast

I updated my Wordpress Website to version 5.5.1 I noticed that some URLs changed.

**Bevor the update my Urls looked like this:**

- Links to the category page: my/website/category/my-category-name
- Links to the articles: my/website/category/my-article-name

**After the update I have it this way**

- Links to the category page: my/website/my-category-name (note that /category/ is gone)
- Links to the articles: my/website/category/my-article-name

**My Permalink settings in Wordpress:**

- The permalinks are set to show the include the category base (): /%category%/%postname%/.
- The optional area are blank to make use wordpress default settings.

I did some testing with those settings, such as trying to set different names for the category base, but it diddn't seem to have any effect. How can I restore the the old URL structure, so that /category/ is included in the category URLs again?
Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to simply refresh the permalinks? either by just going to permalink settings page and just save or by changing them and switch back? Have you checked if your .htaccess is somehow changed?

Comment: when I do this my htaccess is deleted.

Comment: Hmm, then just save it before you save the permalinks, perform the save and then manually restore the .htaccess content. If you have nothing weird in that htaccess it should be a default WP htaccess which you can find here https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: I have lots of 301 redirect for old pages there, but nothing special

Comment: Just store them temporarily somewhere else, save and then add them again. Just a test

Answer (score 0):

Someone stored wrong data in the root directory that causes this issue.